# How to fix GraalVM Warning: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal

Tags: javascript, warnings, nashorn, graalvm

I just downloaded and install the latest graalvm, got the warning while run js
what I'm missing yet, how to avoid it?

```
C:\>java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.2.0 (build 11.0.16+8-jvmci-22.2-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.2.0 (build 11.0.16+8-jvmci-22.2-b06, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>js -version
GraalVM JavaScript (GraalVM CE Native 22.2.0)

C:\>%JAVA_HOME%/bin/js
Aug 10, 2022 6:57:03 AM org.graalvm.shadowed.org.jline.utils.Log logr
WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
>
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue ?